# перенос проекта yii2 + nodejs на другой сервер

Tags: node.js, yii2, node-modules

помогите разобраться. Задача перенести проект (yii2 + node js) на новый vds сервер. Сервер вроде сконфигурировал.перенес yii часть. сайт запустился. но вот калькулятор не работает(он должен рассчитать и создать проект схему с расчетами).npn поставил.gulp поставил. npn install делал в папке с package.json и npm rebuild делал, калькулятор так и не заработал.
в консоли при клике на расчет появляется ошибка:

```
Object { readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: getResponseHeader(), getAllResponseHeaders: getAllResponseHeaders(), setRequestHeader: setRequestHeader(), overrideMimeType: overrideMimeType(), statusCode: statusCode(), abort: abort(), state: state(), always: always(), catch: catch(), … }
bundle.js:1:6515
```

```
responseText: "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN\">       \n<html><head>\n<title>404 Not Found</title>\n</head><body>\n<h1>Not Found</h1>\n<p>The requested URL /calculate was not found on this server.</p>\n<hr>\n<address>Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at sjecproject.fvds.ru  Port 80</address>\n</body></html>\n"
```

я сам php-ник в js особо не понимаю, тем более в node.я конечно читать начал, но сроки горят.пните хоть в нужном направлении. Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0):

похоже, что в апаче нужно настроить обработку nodejs.
разрулить какие урлы будут идти на ноду а какие на php
И как минимум они должны вести на разные порты, например 80 и 8080

Comment: @schevgeny  у меня есть конфиг для nginx для этого сайта.но с nginx я хуже чем с  apache. не поможете?

Comment: как я писал для начала убедитесь что nginx висит на 80 или 443 порту, а node например на 3000